# video player in flutter with audio in background support

Tags: flutter

hello folks i want to make and app for ios and android , do you know any package for flutter for video player with audio support when the app is on background ? thanks you very much for any help.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:just_audio/just_audio.dart';
import 'package:just_audio_background/just_audio_background.dart';
import 'package:chewie/chewie.dart'; // Importa el paquete chewie
import 'package:video_player/video_player.dart'; // Importa el paquete video_player
```

i am trying to found a solution with the packages above.